# Windows file names without brackets

Tags: windows, rename, png

I have a Windows folder containing 73 images.

I'd like to rename them from `something(1).png` to `something-1.png` (... to `something-73.png`. How can I do that?

- <kbd>F2</kbd> does not seem to work
- Rightclick and rename adds brackets automatically

Comment: Windows will automatically add brackets if you try to rename it to a filename that already exists. Rename everything to something else first, then you can rename it back. To rename everything back, either do it one file at a time, write a script in powershell or use a file rename program.

Comment: [PowerToys](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/powertoys/) has a utility that allows you to rename files.

Comment: And there are some good tools, such as free-for-personal-use https://www.bulkrenameutility.co.uk/

Comment: PowerToys has been amazing. Thanks a lot!